# IOS, in the <input> type=text, text doesn't show full text and also cursor disappears

Tags: ios, input, text, cursor

In the input type text, there are issue about display.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imdxK.png)
When I entered long text and then reached the end of input area(input field exceeds), it doesn't show rest of text and cursor disappear too.
I checked this issue in the Safari, and my app. (In the Android, there is no issue.)

Here is my code and css.

##########code#############

```
<input id="write_msg" type="text" name="" placeholder="Write here" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
```

##########CSS#############

```
#footer .ft_input_wrap > li.ft_input_box {margin-left: 62px; height: 60px;}

#footer .ft_input_wrap > li.ft_input_box input {line-height: 24px, text-indent: 10px; height: 24px; width: calc(100%-70px); fint-size: 106.3%; caret-color: #fe3cbc; word-break: normal; margin-top: 15px; padding-top: 3px;}

.dvc .ios #footer .ft_input_wrap > li.ft_input_box input{line-height: 24px; height:24px;}
```

Is there any way to make visible all text????

I checked almost stackoverflow's posting, but I couldn't find answer....